# Thymeleaf String Split issue

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a string `YES:YES;No:No;NA:NA`, I want to split by colon and make it as an array,And iterate an array and  display it in the drop down box. Is it possible? Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the template use:

```
${#strings.arraySplit(yourVar, ':')}
```